# Can I install Virtualbox and Ubuntu on an MSI GP62 laptop?

Tags: virtualbox, msi

I'm considering purchasing the laptop below:

[MSI GP62 MVR Leopard Pro-218 Intel Core i7-6700HQ 15.6" VR Ready Laptop With 16GB Memory, 1TB Hard Drive, Windows 10](http://www.frys.com/product/8988933?site=sr:SEARCH:MAIN_RSLT_PG)

**Will I have any issues installing VirtualBox and the latest version of Ubuntu on this laptop?**

I'll be using the laptop for Linux web development and some graphic design (like Photoshop). After entensive research I chose it because it's possible to replace the hard drive and memory and it's 15 inches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you will encounter graphic and booting problem on this laptop, so you have to tweak some kernel setting on to getting Ubuntu work properly.

If you look at [msi](/questions/tagged/msi) tag page, you'll see some MSI laptop owner reportedly having boot lead them to black screen, this is because MSI laptops have needed various boot parameters.

The `nomodeset` option is required if booting with [nvidia](/questions/tagged/nvidia), but if booting with [intel](/questions/tagged/intel) video then a [intel](/questions/tagged/intel) parameter is required.

#### Your question

> Will I have any issues installing latest version of Ubuntu on this laptop?

Yes, definitely you will encounter issues. Be sure to check [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) to resolve the issue.

> Will I have any issues installing VirtualBox on this laptop?

I don't know about virtualbox, but according to [Google](http://google.com) search, MSI user haven't occurred virtualbox error, so the possibility have virtualbox error are small, I assume it's safe.

Comment: Thanks Liso. I also asked this question on Quora and it appears I shouldn't have issues installing VirtualBox and Ubuntu on the MSI computer I want to buy.

Comment: Be prepare for problem that may bother you when installing ubuntu, stay Ubuntus ;)